# How can I get ConentType in a Java web service?

Tags: java, web-services

What is the equivalent of

```
String ClientContentType=this.Context.Request.ContentType;
```

in a Java web service.

Comment: Have you tried "request.getContentType();" ?

Comment: Which web service library are you using? CXF? Metro? Some skeleton code would be handy.

Comment: i don't know about which library i am using but my tool is netbeans6.9, and using JAX-WS.